# How do I use python to parse large wikipedia dump in .xml.bz2 format using multistream so I don't have to open the whole file?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, large-files, file-read, bz2

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download#English-language_Wikipedia) is the link to the article talking about the wikipedia dump and how to use multistreaming so that I don't have to open the entire file to parse it. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bz2.html#bz2.BZ2Decompressor) is the library that it suggests using.

My problem is that I don't know how to to properly use the index file or that library to correctly parse the file. When I try to decompress it I just read a series of empty bytes "b''". What I want to do is be able to parse the file a few thousand characters at a time so that I can then use them into my NLP application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this? I'm working on the same problem

Comment: @AlexKrantz I wish I had but no, have you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

I found some code from the [wikidump link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download#English-language_Wikipedia)!

code link is : https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/plugins/gitiles/operations/dumps/+/ariel/toys/bz2multistream

if you read the wikiarticles.py script patiently, you'll find code snippet below:

```
def retrieve_text(self, title, offset):
    '''
    retrieve the page text for a given title from the xml file
    this does decompression of a bz2 stream so it's more expsive than
    other parts of this class
    arguments:
    title  -- the page title, with spaces and not underscores, case sensitive
    offset -- the offset in bytes to the bz2 stream in the xml file which contains
              the page text
    returns the page text or None if no such page was found
    '''
    self.xml_fd.seek(offset)
    unzipper = bz2.BZ2Decompressor()
    out = None
    found = False
    try:
        block = self.xml_fd.read(262144)
        out = unzipper.decompress(block)
    # hope we got enough back to have the page text
    except:
        raise
    # format of the contents (and there are multiple pages per stream):
    #   <page>
    #   <title>AccessibleComputing</title>
    #   <ns>0</ns>
    #   <id>10</id>
    # ...
    #   </page>
```

so for your question, maybe you should do follow steps:

1. read the wiki-multistream-index.txt.gz file ,retrive the offsets of articles
2. seek the wiki-multistream-pages.txt.gz file through offsets
3. deal with block of bytes you've read from step 2
4. repeat step 2 and 3, process all the pages in wikidump file

attention in step 2, you should first get the file descriptor use python open function, and save the fd ref to a variable, then you can use fd.seek(offset) jump to the offset, and you must call fd.read(block_size_bytes) to read pages data out.

again, read the wikiarticles.py and you'll get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Almost four years after the question was asked...

Here is an implementation based on the code mentioned in KevinLoveCherry's answer.  The index file gives you the offset, page id, and page title.  This code reads the multistream dump file and extracts out the desired article's wikitext.  This implementation runs in about 0.1 seconds on my 2022 laptop, reading a recent 21GB single-file full dump of English Wikipedia.

Call the function `get_wikitext()` to obtain the text of an article.  Pass in either the `offset` and the `page_id`, or the `offset` and the page `title`.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import bz2

def get_wikitext(dump_filename, offset, page_id=None, title=None, namespace_id=None, verbose=True, block_size=256*1024):
    """Extract wikitext from a multistream dump file.                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    Requires the offset (in bytes) from the start of the dump file.                                                                                                                                          
    This can be obtained from the index file.                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    Pass in some of either the page_id, namespace_id, or title of the                                                                                                                                        
    page you're looking for.                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    """
    unzipper = bz2.BZ2Decompressor()

    # Read the compressed stream, decompress the data                                                                                                                                                        
    uncompressed_data = b""
    with open(dump_filename, "rb") as infile:
        infile.seek(int(offset))

        while True:
            compressed_data = infile.read(block_size)
            try:
                uncompressed_data += unzipper.decompress(compressed_data)
            except EOFError:
                # We've reached the end of the stream                                                                                                                                                        
                break
            # If there's no more data in the file                                                                                                                                                            
            if compressed_data == '':
        # End if we've finished reading the stream                                                                                                                                                   
        if unzipper.need_input:
                    break
        # Otherwise we've failed to correctly read all of the stream                                                                                                                                 
        raise Exception("Failed to read a complete stream")

    # Extract out the page                                                                                                                                                                                   
    # Format of the contents (and there are multiple pages per stream):                                                                                                                                      
    #   <page>                                                                                                                                                                                               
    #   <title>AccessibleComputing</title>                                                                                                                                                                   
    #   <ns>0</ns>                                                                                                                                                                                           
    #   <id>10</id>                                                                                                                                                                                          
    # ...                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    #   </page>                                                                                                                                                                                              

    uncompressed_text = uncompressed_data.decode("utf-8")
    xml_data = "<root>" + uncompressed_text + "</root>"
    root = ET.fromstring(xml_data)
    for page in root.findall("page"):
        if title is not None:
            if title != page.find("title").text:
                continue
        if namespace_id is not None:
            if namespace_id != int(page.find("ns").text):
                continue
        if page_id is not None:
            if page_id != int(page.find("id").text):
                continue
        # We've found what we're looking for                                                                                                                                                                 
        revision = page.find("revision")
        wikitext = revision.find("text")
        return wikitext.text

    # We failed to find what we were looking for                                                                                                                                                             
    return None


def example_usage():
    index_line = "600:12:Anarchism"
    offset, page_id, title = index_line.split(":")
    dump_file = "enwiki-dump/enwiki-20231101-pages-articles-multistream.xml.bz2"

    wikitext = get_wikitext(dump_file, int(offset), page_id=int(page_id))
    print(wikitext)
```